# Should you use Euler's generalization of fermat's little theorem for primality testing?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primality-test

The title is a bit long, but i think it explains my question well.

Let's say we want to test if an integer p is prime

With Fermat's Little Theorem this is a simple check if

$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 (mod \ p)$

But using the Euler's version:

If $gcd(a,n) = 1, $ then $\ a^{\Phi(n)} \equiv 1 (mod\ n)$

Can we say with a high probability that n is a prime in this case?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. How do you propose to compute $\Phi(n)$ without knowing the prime factors of $n$? A better primality test that refines the Fermat test is the Miller-Rabin test.

Comment: Exactly in the generalized version, as i understand it there is nothing that says that "n is a prime" so we can't really use it to test for primality, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot say that $n$ is prime, given $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \bmod n$; see **Carmichael numbers**:

[Understanding Carmichael Number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485569/understanding-carmichael-number)

[Fermat primality test $\gcd$ condition and carmichael numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406533/fermat-primality-test-gcd-condition-and-carmichael-numbers)

Comment: Yeah i guess my question was a bit vague on this part. I know that we get a probability. But i do wonder if we can use Euler's generalized version to confirm if an integer p is prime.

Comment: No, $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\bmod n$ also holds for non-primes $n$.

Comment: Ok, that is what i wanted to know. That is that Euler's generalization of fermat's little theorem does not tell us if an integer n is a prime or not since it holds for non-primes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) does not guarantee p is prime. What will, as you can see if you find it in the linked page, is Lehmer's theorem. Euler's theorem is nearly pointless.